# Why is my JavaScript Code not playing Music?

Tags: javascript

I want that my buttons ( Home, About, Blog ) on my website plays some sound or music when someone is clicking on them. Now I tried and tried, but cant find out the error in the javascript code.

```
<body onload="htmlIsReady()">
<script type="text/javascript">


var audio;

var audioLink;


window.onmessage = function(event)  {
if (event.data.data) {
//Passes the audio url to the new variable
    audioLink = event.data.data;
//Created a new audio object with the received audio url        
audio = new Audio('URL of AUDIO-FILE');         
                }
            };


function htmlIsReady() {
window.parent.postMessage("html_is_ready", "*");  
 }  

//Funcion that plays the audio
function playAudio() {
 audio.play.play();   
 }

</script>

 // Button that executes the function that plays the audio everytime it's 
 clicked 
 <button class="button" onclick="playAudio()">Play</button>

 </body>
```

Comment: `audio = new Audio('URL of AUDIO-FILE'); ` - did you redact the URL or is this what your code says? Easy way to debug is to check your Network Tab in your dev tools and see if your browser is making a request for the audio file. If it's returning a 404/500, that'll point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `audio.play.play()`, which should be: `audio.play()`. However, you also haven't provided any actual proper URL/relative filepath as the audio source and at the moment your `audio` variable is never actually assigned as a `new Audio`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not too clear why you're using **window.onmessage** to obtain the url of the audio file but it won't work no matter what because **event.data.data** is simply wrong. To obtain the data of a posted message you have to use **event.data**.

Furthermore here you're assigning the data to a variable called **audioLink**

```
audioLink = event.data.data;
```

but don't actually use it for the instantiation of your HtmlAudioElement **audio**.

Lastly, **audio.play.play();** is wrong. To start playback you simply use the play() method on the audio object - audio.play().

Here's a working example:

```js
var audio;
var audioLink;

function playAudio() {
  audio.play();
}

window.onmessage = function(event) {
  if (event.data) {
    audioLink = event.data;
    audio = new Audio(audioLink);
  }
};

window.postMessage("https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.ogg", "*");
```

```html
<button class="button" onclick="playAudio()">Play</button>
```